# Utilizar el Do while en una clase

Tags: java

Hola soy nuevo en programacion y necesito ayuda. Estoy haciendo un programa de calificacion escolar mediante una clase, pero quisiera saber como puedo incluir el do while correctamente que cuando el usuario diga Si  empieze de nuevo la clase. Antes hize un sistema similar y lo pude lograr pero ahora ya se me complico bastante

```
package Escuela;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Escuela {

public void calificacion() {
    Scanner entradaesc = new Scanner(System.in);
 

    System.out.print("Por favor de introducir el nombre del alumno: ");
    String nombre = entradaesc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en programacion:");
     float programacion = entradaesc.nextFloat();
     System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en español:");
     float español = entradaesc.nextFloat();
     System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en ciencias naturales:");
     float cienciasnaturales = entradaesc.nextFloat();
     System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en matematicas:");
     float matematicas = entradaesc.nextFloat();
     
     float resultado = (matematicas + cienciasnaturales + español + programacion) / 4;
     String r = String.format("%.1f", resultado).replace(",", ".");
     System.out.println("El alumno llamado " + nombre + " tuvo una calificacion de: " + r);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

A ver si te sirve

Básicamente a tu método calificaciones, le he agregado el "do while", y además una pregunta, si pulsas s, continua metiendo alumnos, si pulsas m, los muestra, si pulsas otras tecla sale del programa.

Con la opción m, agregué un ArrayList que almacena todos los alumnos y los muestra

```
public class Escuela {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        calificaciones();
    }
    public static void calificaciones(){
    
        Scanner entradaesc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre;
        String nAlumno;
        float programacion;
        float español;
        float cienciasnaturales;
        float matematicas;
        float resultado;
        ArrayList<String> alumnos = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        do{
            System.out.print("Por favor de introducir el nombre del alumno: ");
            nombre = entradaesc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en programacion:");
            programacion = entradaesc.nextFloat();
            //convertimos el float a String
            String p = String.valueOf(programacion);  
            System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en español:");
            //convertimos el float a String
            español = entradaesc.nextFloat();
            String e = String.valueOf(español);  
            System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en ciencias naturales:");
            cienciasnaturales = entradaesc.nextFloat();
            //convertimos el float a String
            String c = String.valueOf(cienciasnaturales);  
            System.out.print("Escriba la calificacion que tuvo en matematicas:");
            matematicas = entradaesc.nextFloat();
            //convertimos el float a String
            String m = String.valueOf(matematicas);  
 
            resultado = (matematicas + cienciasnaturales + español + programacion) / 4; 
            String r = String.format("%.1f", resultado).replace(",", ".");
            System.out.println("El alumno llamado " + nombre + " tuvo una calificacion de: " + r);
            entradaesc.nextLine();
        
            //agregamos los datos al ArrayList
            alumnos.add(nombre);
            alumnos.add(p);
            alumnos.add(e);
            alumnos.add(c);
            alumnos.add(m);
            alumnos.add(r);
        
            //mostramos el menú en pantalla
            System.out.println("Escriba 's' para agregar más alumnos \n "
                + "Escriba 'm' para ver todos los alumnos \n "
                + "Pulse cualquier tecla para salir");
            nAlumno = entradaesc.nextLine();
        
        }while(nAlumno.equals("s"));  //si se teclea 's' continuamos en el bucle while
    
        //si se ha teclado 'm', pasamos por el if y mostramos el ArrayList
        if (nAlumno.equals("m")){
            System.out.println(alumnos);
        }
    }
}
```